# How do you use EF Core to simultaneously insert into multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core 6.0.1, using it with Blazor (WebAssembly), .NET 6.0, and Visual Studio 2022. I am creating a database of internal software projects, including their author(s) and maintainer(s).

I am having trouble getting EF Core to take in a List of `Author`s / List of `Maintainer`s as part of creating a new `SoftwareItem` from a webform submission.

`SoftwareItem` in defined (in part) as follows:

```
public class SoftwareItem
{
        [Key]
        public int SoftwareId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string CurrentVersion { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }
        
        public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
                
        public List<Maintainer> Maintainers { get; set;}
    
        [other properties omitted]

}
```

An `Author` is defined as follows:

```
public class Author
{
        [Key]
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public int SoftwareItemId { get; set; }

        public int ProgrammerId { get; set; }

        public Programmer Programmer { get; set; }
}
```

`Maintainer` is identical, except for having a `MaintainerId` instead of an `AuthorId`.

`Programmer` is defined as:

```
public class Programmer
{
        [Key]
        public int ProgrammerId { get; set; }

        public string ProgrammerName { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core created the tables for me based on a migration, and I have manually populated the `Programmer` table with the nine people who might be an `Author` and/or a `Maintainer`.

I have a webform where the user can create a new `SoftwareItem`, with pre-populated drop-downs for `Author`s and `Maintainer`s that, after querying the database, contain the potential `ProgrammerName`s. The user can assign up to three `Author`s and up to three `Maintainer`s before submitting the webform (via an Author1 dropdown, an Author2 dropdown etc.) Submitting the webform calls the `InsertSoftware` method, included below.

Note that I'm not a fan of the repetition between the `Author` logic and `Maintainer` logic, and the List should probably be a HashSet (in case the same author is set in `Author1` and `Author2`) but those are issues for another day. The `Author1` and similar variables are the int IDs set by the webform. I've previously verified they are being set to the appropriate values via a JavaScript alert. An ID of 0 means the value was never set (e.g. there is no second author).

The `SoftwareItem` here is instantiated as a new object on `OnIntializedAsync` and bound as the webform's model.

```
public async Task InsertSoftware()
{
     List<int> authorIdsToAdd = new List<int>();

     authorIdsToAdd.Add(Author1);
     authorIdsToAdd.Add(Author2);
     authorIdsToAdd.Add(Author3);

     SoftwareItem.Authors = new List<Author>();

     foreach (int author in authorIdsToAdd) 
     {
          if (author != 0)
          {
               foreach (Programmer programmer in ProgrammerList)
               {
                    if (programmer.ProgrammerId == author)
                    {
                         Author addedAuthor = new Author();
                         addedAuthor.Programmer = new Programmer();

                         addedAuthor.Programmer.ProgrammerId = author;
                            
                         SoftwareItem.Authors.Add(addedAuthor);
                    }
                }
           }
      }

      [repeat code for the Maintainers]

      await Http.PostAsJsonAsync("api/softwareitem", SoftwareItem);
      Navigation.NavigateTo("software/fetchsoftware");
}
```

The `SoftwareItem` API is (in part) as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] SoftwareItem softwareItem)
{
      _context.Software.Add(softwareItem);            
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

      return Ok(softwareItem);
}
```

My understanding from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566424/how-to-insert-data-into-multiple-tables-with-a-foreign-key-using-ef-core) is that if objects have been instantiated for a navigation property when the parent entity is added and saved to the database context, then EF Core will also add the new navigation property values to their appropriate tables. However, that isn't happening, and all I'm getting is a 500 error in the console.

What I'm expecting is that...

1. A new entry will be inserted into the `SoftwareItem` table
2. New entries will be inserted into the `Author` table, containing an auto-incremented `AuthorId`, the `SoftwareItem`'s `SoftwareItemId`, and the `ProgrammerId` from the webform
3. New entries will be inserted into the `Maintainer` table, containing an auto-incremented `MaintainerId`, the `SoftwareItem`'s `SoftwareItemId`, and the `ProgrammerId` from the webform.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's a bit difficult to make out what your code is precisely doing but there are a few issues I see.

First, with entities you should always avoid ever reinitializing navigation property lists. During inserts it's "ok", but anywhere else it would lead to bugs/errors so it's better to simply not see it in the code. Pre-initialize your properties in the entity itself:

```
public class SoftwareItem
{
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; } = new List<Author>();
    public virtual ICollection<Maintainer> Maintainers { get; set;} = new List<Maintainer>();
}
```

This ensures the collections are ready to go when you need them for a new entity.

Next, it can be helpful to structure your code to avoid things like module level variables. Your InsertSoftware() method references an instance of SoftwareItem and it isn't clear where, or what this reference would be pointing at. If you have a method chain that loaded a particular software item instance to be updated, pass the reference through the chain of methods as a parameter. This helps encapsulate the logic. You should also look to define a scope for whenever you are referencing a DbContext. With Blazor this needs to be done a bit more explicitly to avoid DbContext instances from being too long-lived. Long-lived DbContext instances are a problem because they lead to performance degradation as they track increasing numbers of entities, and can easly become "poisoned" with invalid entities that prevent things like `SaveChanges()` calls from succeeding. Keep instances alive only as long as absolutely necessary. I would strongly recommend looking at unit of work patterns to help encapsulate the lifetime scope of a DbContext. Ideally entities loaded by a DbContext should not be passed outside of that scope to avoid issues and complexity with detached or orphaned entities.

Next, it is important to know when you are looking to create new entities vs. reference existing data. Code like this is a big red flag:

```
Author addedAuthor = new Author();
addedAuthor.Programmer = new Programmer();

addedAuthor.Programmer.ProgrammerId = author;
```

From what I can make out, the Author (and Maintainer) are linking entities so we will want to create one for each "link" between a software item and a programmer. However, Programmer is a reference to what should be an existing row in the database.

If you do something like:

```
var programmer = new Programmer { ProgrammerId == author };
```

then associate that programmer as a reference to another entity, you might guess this would tell EF to find and associate an existing programmer.. Except it doesn't. You are telling EF to associate a *new* programmer with a particular ID. Depending on how EF has been configured for that entity (whether to use an identity column for the PK or not) this will result in one of three things happening if that programmer ID already exists:

1. A new programmer is created with an entirely new ID (identity gives it a new id and ProgrammerId is ignored)
2. EF throws an exception when it tries to insert a new programmer with the same ID. (Duplicate PK)
3. EF throws an exception if you tell it add a new programmer and it happens to already be tracking an instance with the same ID.

So, to fix this, load your references:

```
 List<int> authorIdsToAdd = new List<int>();

 // likely need logic to only add authors if they are selected, and unique.
 authorIdsToAdd.Add(Author1);
 authorIdsToAdd.Add(Author2);
 authorIdsToAdd.Add(Author3);

// Define your own suitable scope mechanism for this method or method chain
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var softwareItem = new SoftwareItem { /* populate values from DTO or Map from DTO */ }
    // Retrieve references
    var authors = await context.Programmers.Where(x => authorIdsToAdd.Contains(x.ProgrammerId)).ToListAsync();

    foreach(var author in authors)
    { 
        softwareItem.Authors.Add(new Author { Programmer = author });
    }

    // Continue for Maintainers...

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: How do I get the `AppDbContext` definition into the `CreateSoftware` class? The `AppDbContext` class is in the `SoftwareCensus.Server.Data` namespace, and the code you tweaked is in `SoftwareCensus.Client.Pages.Software`. If I try to use `using SoftwareCensus.Server.Data` to bring in the `AppDbContext`, I get `the type or namespace name 'Server' does not exist in the namespace 'SoftwareCensus' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` I assume this is Blazor keeping the Client and Server projects apart from each other.

Comment: Pass the necessary data into the `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] SoftwareItem softwareItem)` method in your service and perform the creation and referencing within the scope there. (rather than creating the instances to populate a detached entity and passing the entity in) So instead of passing a SoftwareItem entity, pass the values & keys as parameters or a DTO to this service to find and create your entity within the scope of the DbContext.