# How can I add an Entity Framework Core n-m self-referencing entity using an explicit join table with payload for SQL-Server?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a simple simulation for a market with .NET 6. For that I want to store products in a SQL Server database.

Each product can consist of other products (as materials to construct it, just for naming clarification). A basic material product has no products as materials, so the `materials list` can be empty.

A `productDto` stores its materials as a `Dictionary<Product, int>` to keep track of how much is needed of each material. This is stored as `Amount` in `ProductMaterialsJoin`.

I have created entities as follows:

```cs
    public class ProductEntity
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
            [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public double PriceEuro { get; set; }
    
            public virtual List<ProductEntity> Materials { get; set; }
            public virtual List<ProductMaterialsJoin> ProductMaterials { get; set; } = new ();
        }
    
    public class ProductMaterialsJoin
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    
            [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public ProductEntity ProductEntity { get; set; }
    
            [ForeignKey("MaterialId")]
            public int MaterialId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public ProductEntity MaterialEntity { get; set; }
    
            [Required]
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }
```

I did not want to have a `Materials` list in the `Product Entity`, because everything is already stored in the join entity, but I dont know how I can skip it.

The fluent configuration is as follows:

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<ProductEntity>()
                    .HasMany<ProductEntity>(p => p.Materials)
                    .WithMany()
                    .UsingEntity<ProductMaterialsJoin>(
                    l => l.HasOne(j => j.ProductEntity)
                          .WithMany(p => p.ProductMaterials)
                          .HasForeignKey(j => j.ProductId),
                    r => r.HasOne(j => j.MaterialEntity)
                          .WithMany()
                          .HasForeignKey(j => j.MaterialId)
                    );
            }
```

**My Question:**

I am not sure, if this EF representation is the model I have with my DTOs.
Referencing the [Microsoft headlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many), what I want to do would be a self-referencing many-to-many and join table with payload. By hand, I would have created a join table with two foreign keys that reference the main product and the ingrediens along with the amount in one row, but if I execute the code above, EF seems to not do that.

How can I get rid of the `Materials` list in the `Product Entity`?

Comment: if your problem is insert data ,you can this is site :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566424/how-to-insert-data-into-multiple-tables-with-a-foreign-key-using-ef-core

Comment: Relationships are between two *entities*, but these entities do not need to be different, i.e. "self" relationships are not a problem, if configured properly. From what you have show, it is unclear what `Materials` and `ProductMaterials` collections represent, and how they are configured. So please include the fluent configuration in order to see if it is correct, and then we can discuss other potential issues.

Comment: @Ivan-Stoev I have added the fluent configuration as requested and tried to explain my problem better. The ProductMaterials List should store all "sub" products (materials) together with the amount that is needed of each to create it. The Materials List is not really needed imo. but I dont know how to configure everything without it. My wish would be to only have ProductMaterials, because inside it all materials are already stored

Comment: The entity model is ok. Left and right (`l => ...` and `r => ...` lines) must be exchanged (`UsingEntity` first argument is `configureRight`, then `configureLeft`), but that's probably not essential. The `Materials` skip navigation property can easily be eliminated, but that's not a problem as well. May be adding to the question the dto and the map/add code which is causing you problems? Because I have no issues adding new `ProductEntity`-es with or w/o `ProductMaterials`, so most likely the problem is with mapping/applying the dto.

Comment: @IvanStoev does it matter what is mapped to left and right or is it interchangeable? 
Also how can I remove the `Materials List`? Would I have to use only `modelBuilder.Entity<ProductMaterialsJoin>` and configure it without `.UsingEntity`? 
I will try to debug more and then further update my question so that it is better understandable. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Since I cannot paste code here, posted a partial answer covering what we have commented so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left and right join entity configuration of `UsingEntity` should be exchanged

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductEntity>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Materials)
    .WithMany()
    .UsingEntity<ProductMaterialsJoin>(
    r => r.HasOne(j => j.MaterialEntity)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(j => j.MaterialId),
    l => l.HasOne(j => j.ProductEntity)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProductMaterials)
            .HasForeignKey(j => j.ProductId)
    );
```

but this is just to get the correct `ProductEntity.Materials` list elements for navigation. By correct, I mean to include the entities used as material by that product, i.e. having `ProductId == entity.Id`. The way you did it, `ProductEntity.Materials` includes the entities, the product is used by, i.e. having `MaterialId == entity.Id`.

If you don't need the `Materials` navigation collection, just remove it from the model

```cs
public class ProductEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double PriceEuro { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ProductMaterialsJoin> ProductMaterials { get; set; } = new();
}
```

and use the following fluent configuration (basically the left and right part of the `UsingEntity`, but separately, to just define two one-to-many relationships between entity and join entity, which at the end results in one  many-to-many self relationship):

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductMaterialsJoin>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ProductEntity)
    .WithMany(e => e.ProductMaterials)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // delete join, if product is deleted (default action for required relationships)

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductMaterialsJoin>()
    .HasOne(e => e.MaterialEntity)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MaterialId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); // forbid deletion of a material that is used by a product
```

This should not change your database model, so no migration should be needed.

From here, you can work with join entity the same way as you work with any "many" side entity of a relationship. You can add/update/delete them through `ProductMaterials` collection of the parent `ProductEntity`, or directly via its own `DbSet<ProductMaterialsJoin>` by playing with `ProductEntity` and `MaterialEntity` reference navigation properties, and/or `ProductId` and `MaterialId` explicit foreign key properties depending of what you are getting as input for the desired operation.

If you have a concrete issue with specific operation receiving DTOs as input, please include it in the question and I'll be glad to help resolving it.

Comment: My mssms did not show the key icon, when I opened the table, but I tested your suggestion and it works as I wanted it. So EF seems to do everything right, might be an issue with mssms. I was just confused, that it looked different, than if I would create the tables by hand. Thank you very much for your help.